# Modulo polynomial in ring theory

Tags: ring-theory

Let $x^4-16$ be an element of the polynomial ring $E= \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and use the bar notation to denote passage to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^4-16)$. Find a polynomial of degree $\leq 3$ that is congruent to $7x^{13} -11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3$ modulo $x^4-16$. Can anyone help understand how to mod out polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

Note that modulo $x^4-16$, $x^4-16 = 0$, so $x^4 = 16$. Thus you can replace every copy of $x^4$ with 16. For one, you can write $7x^{13} = 7x\cdot(x^4)^3 = 7x\cdot (16)^3$, and similarly with the other terms in your polynomial.

...you get the idea.

Comment: Hmm this might be a stupid question but... does this work if we view $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module? I am asking because, if we view $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a module over itself (i.e. a ring) and then quotient out by the submodule generated by $x^4-16$ then sure. We get:

$$\overline{7x^{13}} = 7x^9 \overline{x^4} = 7x^9 (\overline{x^4 - (x^4 -16)} = 7x^9 \overline{16} = \overline{(16)(7)x^9}.$$

But if we view this as a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ how do you justify this?

Comment: Yes it still works. The ideal $(x^4-16)$ *is* a submodule, so you can quotient out by it. The equivalence relation corresponding to $(x^2-16)$ viewed as an ideal or a submodule are the same, and as sets the quotient module/quotient rings are exactly the same. Your question has nothing to do with the module or ring structure. You're simply asking about a way to rewrite individual elements. Yes you're right you can't "multiply" elements in a module, but your question is about elements, and to prove that eg. $x^8 = (x^4)^2 = 16$, the *existence* of a ring structure where it makes sense is enough.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was badly phrased. Anyway, the question clearly states that here we view $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a ring so we are done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way to do this is by performing Euclidean division of $7x^{13} -11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3$ by $x^4 - 16$. In this way you get a polynomial $r(x)$ of degree less than $x^4 - 16$, so of degree at most $3$, and a polynomial $q(x)$ such that

$$7x^{13} -11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3  = q(x)(x^4 -16) + r(x)$$

You see that $r(x)$ is congruent to $7x^{13} -11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3$ modulo $x^4 -16$.

Note that this will always work as long as the polynomial that defines your ideal has leading coefficient $1$  (or more generally an element invertible in the base ring).

Answer (score 1):

By using the long division i was able to obtain $7x^{13} - 11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3 = q(x)(x^4 -16) +r(x)$ where $q(x)= 7x^9+101x^5+1621x$ and $r(x) = -2x^3+25936x+3$ since i was looking for $r(x)$ then the polynomial is $-2x^3+25936x+3$

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\,\ x^4-2^4\!:\,\ x^4\equiv 2^4\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{x^{4n}}\equiv 2^{4n}$

$\! \begin{align}{\rm therefore}\quad &\ \ 7\,\color{#c00}{x^{12}}x -11\,\color{#c00}{x^8}\,x + 5\,\color{#c00}{x^4}\,x-2x^3+3\\
 \equiv &\  \ 7\, 2^{12}\,x - 11\, 2^8\, x + 5\, 2^4\, x -2\,x^3+3\quad {\bf QED}\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

It's the remainder of the division of $7x^{13} -11x^9 + 5x^5-2x^3+3$ by $x^4-16$.

Comment: do the long division and what ever the remainder is that will be my polynomial

Comment: It's exactly that, since passing to the quotient ring amounts to killing the dividend.

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes easier to see what is happening by looking at things a different way. Here, just as $p\equiv q \bmod r$ holds for integers precisely when $r \mid (p-q)$, modular arithmetic for polynomials has $p(x)\equiv q(x) \bmod r(x)$ precisely when $r(x)\mid (p(x)-q(x))$

The implication of this is (working modulo $r(x)$) we have $p(x)\equiv p(x)+r(x)s(x)$ for any polynomial $s(x)$ [working over the same ground ring]

The substitution rule here - that one can consistently replace $x^4$ by $16$ in the example in the question reflects the fact that $$x^4=16+(x^4-16)\equiv 16 \bmod (x^4-16)$$